# rails initializer getting executed multiple times in rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, passenger, initializer

I have a an app running on apache + passenger and I have a initializer to initializer rufus scheduler and then schedule jobs.

It seems like the initializer is getting executed multiple times after the app has been started which schedules duplicate jobs within rufus scheduler.

I am not sure why the initializers are getting executed multiple times without a restart.

Comment: I see multiple apache2 pids: root      9382     1  0 16:58 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  9383  9382  0 16:58 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  9398  9382  0 16:58 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  9399  9382  0 16:58 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Initializers are not the right place to do it. Each initializar is executed for every process your web server run. i.e. You apache start 4 process to accept connections to your rails application, your initializer is executed 4 times.

A simple solution would be to use a rake task as part of your deployment strategy.

Comment: How would I initialize a scheduler thread? Part of the iniializer I do this: $scheduler = Rufus::Scheduler.start_new I know this is probably a bad way to use a app wide global variable. How else can I use it? It's a small app so I don't have a deployment process so for this every time I restart the app I should just manually run a rake task or maybe have a shell script to restart and then run a rake task right after it?